# Having trouble retrieving headers from Xamarin.Forms Android webview using ShouldOverrideUrlLoading, always (null)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

I am using a custom webview client `CustomWebviewClient : FormsWebViewClient`

In the overridden function `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IWebResourceRequest request)` I can see the request object, but the `RequestHeaders` are null.

In my `HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer` I'm adding additional headers for my app version like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {Constants.AppHeader, Constants.AppVersion }
                };

Control.LoadUrl(uri, headers);
```

I can see these headers on my site when I dump them, but the `IWebResourceRequest.RequestHeaders` are always `null`

Am I missing something here on the Android side?

I've noticed a couple times on the iOS side that I need to force cast certain objects in order to access their properties/methods like so:

```
var thisresponse = (NSHttpUrlResponse)navigationResponse.Response;

var allOfThem = thisresponse.AllHeaderFields;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there are many existing questions on this topic - https://www.google.com/search?q=ShouldOverrideUrlLoading+requestheaders+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason from the looks of it, it's not possible, is that right? This is always going to be `null`?

Comment: I didn't do any deep research, but the few links I scanned implied that this was just a weird Android behavior

Comment: @Jason thanks, seems to be the case in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code below. `CustomHeaderValue` is the BindableProperty of my CustomHeaderWebView.

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomHeaderWebView), typeof(CustomHeaderWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App14.Droid
{
public class CustomHeaderWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomHeaderWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
{
    Context _localContext;

    public CustomHeaderWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _localContext = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomHeaderWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Android.Webkit.WebView webView = Control as Android.Webkit.WebView;

        if (Control == null)
        {
            webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_localContext);
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["Authorization"] = Element.CustomHeaderValue // Change this string for a different header key
            };

            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            webView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
            webView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);

            webView.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
            webView.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;

            webView.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(headers));
            UrlWebViewSource source = Element.Source as UrlWebViewSource;
            webView.LoadUrl(source.Url, headers);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomWebViewClient : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> headers { get; set; }

    public CustomWebViewClient(Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders)
    {
        headers = requestHeaders;
    }
}
}
```